# What is meaning contain "$" in the key in object on angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I was trying simple test.

This below source is good works.

```
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = angular.module("test", []);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in {'a':'a'}">{{key}}:{{value}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, this below source is not working.

```
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = angular.module("test", []);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in {'$a':'a'}">{{key}}:{{value}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is same only changed key from 'a' to '$a' in repeated target object.

What is meaning contain $ character in object key?

Comment: ngRepeat explicitely ignored properties starting with `$`. I think it does that because those properties are normally reserved to the framework: it uses them for example to be able to associate a DOM node with the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ symbol is used by Angular to reference internal members (aka, Angular specific modules).

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1549